# Will the equal rights amendment actually have an effect on any existing statute?

Tags: constitutional-law

Was watching John Oliver last night and he had a whole feature on the Equal Rights Amendment. What is the point? Are there any current statutes that could be affect by this amendment, anywhere? We have seen what has happened in the past, like with that stupid right to bear arms, and how that has been misapplied.

Comment: Could you please link to the proposed amendment's language or an article explaining it?

Comment: @hszmv https://www.equalrightsamendment.org/

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47445/what-effect-would-the-equal-rights-amendment-have-if-it-ever-were-to-be-ratifie

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes there are already laws in place to deal with discrimination based one one's gender, but according to their website, they feel that those laws are not enforced in a consistent and reasonable way.

Obviously, any law you make that could be interpreted in different ways, probably will have some people who have differing views on it or do not like the way it is enforced.

They have a lengthy list of things they feel are discrimination on their site 
https://www.equalrightsamendment.org/why

To make a long story short, they want the court rulings on gender based issues to be the same from state to state.